# Calculator JAVASCRIPT: problem with the logical part

Tags: javascript

I've made a simple calculator, but it doesn't work properly. So i've a graphical part with a screen, that is where i append number. Then The logical part work basically with to variable, the x that is the previous number before a mathematical sign, and the y that is the number after the sign; that is also a checker that check what is the last sign that the user have chose, and based on that, it sum or divide etc. the x and y in the result function. In the result function is also parsed the x and y,  and after that it is calculated. Here comes the problem, when i try to do 1 +1 = 12 and 11 + 11 = 122, in the y there are no problem, but in the x is added "1" more than requested. (i've done an if that permit to concat string to write multi-digit-number like 11).

Thanks to all in advice :)

(for now i've applied that process only for the number 1
uguale is the egual function)

```
let checker; 
let a;
let x = "";
let y = "";
// funzioni 
function Append (X) {
screen.append(X);
}
uno.addEventListener("click", Uno);
function Uno () {
Append(1); 

if (x == "" && y == "") {
    x = "1";
}
if (x !== "" && checker !== undefined && y == "") {
    y = "1";
} 
else if (x !== "" && y == "" && checker == undefined) {
x = x + "1";
}
else if (x !== "" && y !== "" && checker !== undefined) {
y = y +"1";
}
}
somma.addEventListener("click", Somma);
function Somma () {
Append("+");
checker = "+";
}
sottrazione.addEventListener("click", Sottrazione);
function Sottrazione () {
Append("-"); 
checker = "-"
}
moltiplicazione.addEventListener("click", Moltiplicazione);
function Moltiplicazione () {
Append("*");
checker = "*"
}
divisione.addEventListener("click", Divisione);
function Divisione () {
Append("/"); 
checker = "/"
}
uguale.addEventListener("click", Uguale);
function Uguale () {
if (checker == "+") {
x = parseInt(x);
y = parseInt(y);
console.log((x + y));

}
if (checker == "-") {
    console.log(parseInt(x - y));
    }
    if (checker == "*") {
        console.log(parseInt(x * y));
        }
        if (checker == "/") {
            console.log(parseInt(x / y))
        }
}
```

Comment: It seems that in function Uno() you missed an else if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the second if condition. It is an else if, not an if.
In fact, you add a one to the x var with the first if `if (x == "" && y == "")`.
Then, the x value is "1", but you enter in the `else if (x !== "" && y == "" && checker == undefined)` condition.

Comment: now my calculator work only with two -number like 56777 * 2344, how can i extend it to an infinite lenght like 3*3*3*3? now 3*3*3*3 in my calculator is egual to 999.

Comment: I suggest you to use a stack, a list or similar: you can't declare two variabile and a single sign likw you do now